# Grails specification test with service

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails, spock

I am trying to use service in Spock specification test.

```
 def "Registrate company and user with some valid data"() {
     given:
     RegistrationService registrationService = Mock()
     controller.registrationService = registrationService

     when:
     def data =  registrationService.register('test@test.sk','a','a','a','12345576','159159159','a','a','a','a','a')

     then:
     assert data.instance1.hasErrors() == false
     assert data.instance2.hasErrors() == false
     assert data.instance3.hasErrors() == false
}
```

I am getting Null pointer exception `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'instace1' on null object.`

If I run the service through my controller, then everything works fine.

Service returns this `[instance1:instance1,instance2:instance2,instance3:instance3]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify what the mock `RegistrationService` returns when it's methods are invoked, e.g.

```
def "Registrate company and user with some valid data"() {
    given:
    RegistrationService registrationService = Stub()

    // you should probably be a bit more precise about the arg-list
    registrationService.register(*_) >> 
            [instance1: instance1, instance2: instance2, instance3: instance3]

    controller.registrationService = registrationService

    when:
    def data = registrationService.register('test@test.sk','a','a','a','12345576','159159159','a','a','a','a','a')

    then:
    !data.instance1.hasErrors()
    !data.instance2.hasErrors()
    !data.instance3.hasErrors()
}
```

Notice that it's not necessary to use `assert` in the `then:` block, each statement will be considered successful if it returns a truthy value, or a failure if falsey.

### Update

I notice that the reported error message is

> Cannot get property 'instace1' on null object.

So it looks like you might have a missing "n" in your code somewhere

Comment: Hi, I thank you for your response. I tried your solution, but I still get the same error.

Comment: @Michael.D I've made some changes to the code, can you retry with the code above?

Comment: Your solution works, though now I am getting this error. User.hasErrors() is applicable for argument types: () values: []. By the way, I fixed a typo in my question.

Comment: @Michael.D if this is a unit test you need to use `@Mock(User)` to make methods like `hasErrors()` available

Comment: I have it like this `@Mock([User,Company,Branch])`.